# Need help to map custom color definition into vscode color definition

Tags: visual-studio-code, color-mapping

I want to map this custom color definition into vscode night owl color definition 
but I don't know how to map these into vscode settings.json
Hope that you lot can help me

I am using [this Night Owl theme](https://github.com/sdras/night-owl-vscode-theme) in my visual studio code.

custom color definition:

```
 {
    id: "night-owl",
    name: "Night Owl",
    highlights: {
      background: "#011627",
      text: "#abb2bf",
      variable: "#82AAFF",
      attribute: "#F78C6C",
      definition: "#82AAFF",
      keyword: "#c792ea",
      operator: "#c792ea",
      property: "#fff",
      number: "#F78C6C",
      string: "#ecc48d",
      comment: "#717a8a",
      meta: "#7fdbca",
      tag: "#7fdbca",
    },
  },
```

With this, I can turn my vscode night owl theme to look like this
[image]

Comment: Why you need to map it ? You can directly put these into `setting.json`

Comment: well, I tried.. even double-quoted "id" like this.. but it still showed error.. vscode underlined it.. unrecognizable commands and so on

Comment: have you read the VSC docs about theme customization

Comment: yes, I have... I just don't know the specific syntax.. How should I get these (text: "#abb2bf",
      variable: "#82AAFF",) etc in vscode user settings.json

Answer (score 0):

For background, you have to set `"editor.background"` under `"workbench.colorCustomizations"`. For example, if you add the following segment into your user's `settings.json` file, it will change the background, foreground, activity foreground, and sidebar background.

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "[Night Owl]": {
            "editor.background": "#ff0000",
            "editor.foreground": "#000000",
            "activityBar.foreground": "#00b7ff", //for activity foreground
            "sideBar.background": "#151616" //for sidebar background
        }
    },
```

To customize code, you have to use `"editor.tokenColorCustomizations"`. For example, the following section will customize all comments and functions.

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "[Night Owl]": {
            "comments": "#717272",
            "functions":  "#00b7ff",
        }
    }
```

Hope you got the idea. For more, check the [vscode color theme](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes) section and  [reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color) page. You may also look into [Night Owl's readme file](https://github.com/sdras/night-owl-vscode-theme).

Comment: HA! Hotdog theme. My eyes. I fell for it.